# Nested namespaces vs. ES modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

With traditional JavaScript namespacing techniques I am able to create a nested logical grouping, even over multiple files. How should I replace that with ES modules alias import.

Consider the case where I want all my code in a CompanyName namespace, then group by products and within a product I may have a group of shared functions and these could be grouped by topic (very common in many languages like Java, C# etc.). F.e.

```
CompanyName = {
    ProductName1: {
        Shared: {
            Database: {
                enumerateDatabases: function() {
                    ....
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    ProductName2: {
        ....
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly ES modules allow me to use exactly one alias to create a namespace, f.e.

```
import * as CompanyName from ...
```

An alias like CompanyName only is certainly not specific enough. An alias like

```
import * as CompanyNameProductName1SharedDatabase from...
```

is almost unreadable and a simple alias like

```
import * as Database from...
```

may quickly become ambiguous and I would have to go with aliases like

```
import * as MyDatabase from...
import * as YourDatabase from...
```

Does that mean there is no way of grouping code as shown above? Or should I go with a mixture of both techniques?

Comment: Just curious: how did you refer to the `enumerateDatabases` function when using nested namespaces?

Comment: It certainly looks ugly in this case: 'let dbs = CompanyName.ProductName1.Shared.Database.enumerateDatabases()'. Of course I could use local abbreviations when possible, even for parts of the namespace. The point is, the full namespace is available whenever it is needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I understand correctly ES modules allow me to use exactly one alias to create a namespace

Yes, aliases must be simple identifiers, there is no nesting. Notice that `CompanynameProductname1SharedDatabase` isn't that bad compared to `Companyname.Productname1.Shared.Database` - even in other languages you wouldn't write the whole package name every time, but give it a reasonable alias. Maybe even with abbreviations like `CPSDb`.

> A simple alias like `import * as Database from...` may quickly become ambiguous

No, it should not. It's quite unlikely that Product2 would need to import Product1's database. You would only need to disambiguate if you really have multiple databases in the same module.

Just choose reasonable aliases for the *current* module. That might mean using different aliases depending on where you are importing it, and that's fine:

```
// src/productname1/shared/index.js
import * as Database from './database.js';
```

```
// src/backend/init.js
import * as Productname1SharedDatabase from '/productname1/shared/database.js';
```

Also notice that it's rather uncommon in JS to use namespace imports at all, they're only used when you import many bindings from a module *and* need to disambiguate them from other modules. You'll see

```
import { enumerateDatabase } from './database.js';
```

much more often, and it's clear already that an `enumerateDatabase` function would be found in the database module. Notice that there are no implicit bindings in JavaScript: if you forgot where an identifier came from, you will always find its (import) declaration in the current file so you can easily look it up. Additionally, your IDE will help you by showing where the name resolves to.

Comment: Thanks, many valuable points. What frustrates me a little is that I consider classical namespaces a highly systematic concept. As you write yourself, with ES modules I have to adapt to the case at hand. Multiple databases in one app is almost my daily business because I have to convert and move data from A to B etc. So avoiding clashes and knowing what belongs where is very important for me. I think my main critic is this: in C# and Java or classical JS namespaces you have a waterproof concept to disambiguate and group things. With ES modules it's more like I have to check which alias works...

Comment: @NicolasR You can of course come up with your own convention/scheme for how to build the aliases from the file path (as those are what identifies the module, similar to java packages). The systematic grouping should be done with folders.

Comment: @NicolasR And of course the concept of using nested objects as namespaces is not dead. You still can have a module export an object with properties for its public child namespaces and use that, using modules only for creating each namespace's members in a separate file. (You may however have to worry more about circular dependencies then, when a module imports a "parent")

Comment: Ok, I accept your answer. Maybe one last question: do you know whether I can use the same alias for multiple modules, like f.e. 'import * as CompanyName from "file-system-utils"' and 'import * as CompanyName from "database-utils"'. Then I could have CompanyName as the top level namespace and use object namespaces within the modules. Just out of curiosity...

Comment: No, aliases must not collide within one module's scope, just like other variable declarations. You would rather do `import * as CompanyName from '..';`, and have the root directory export filesystemutils and a databaseutils constants (each imported from their respective modules).

Answer (score 1):

The way you would do it would be

```js
const enumerateDatabases = function() {
        ....
    }
export {
    enumerateDatabases
}
```

and

```js
import {enumerateDatabases as aliasForEnumDbs} from 'xx.js';
```

Comment: Yes, examples like these are shown everywhere but: how do you handle the case that someone else has a function 'enumerateDatabases'? And wasn't it a nice feature to easily recognize where a function comes from when you call it like: 'let dbs = CompanyName.ProductName.Shared.Database.enumerateDatabases()'. Ok, this example is extreme but I hope you get the point.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This certainly works but I am somehow looking for a concept that works for large codebases with numerous potential clashes. Aliasing individual functions seems rather laborious. Imagine 100 utility functions in one module and 50 modules... I accepted Bergis answer because he provides a litte more background and alternatives.